# React Native get notified just before app minimizes but still active

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I need a way to hide sensitive information in a react native app so if you minimize the app and leave your phone unlocked the snapshot of the app in the multitasking view would be blurred and the navigation stack would be switched back to login screen when the app becomes active again.

Even just showing the Login screen just before the app becomes inactive->background would be sufficient but it seems that the `AppState`'s `change` event is called after the state is already changed from active to inactive and at this point the snapshot is already made and the screen changing occurs after the app is restored. This way the screen with the sensitive data is visible in the multitasking.

I know how to make this with ease in native iOS environment but it seems it's not quite that trivial in React Native.

Comment: And why aren't you doing it natively ?

Comment: @Antoine Grandchamp Because the task is to develop the apps in React Native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid here from the native code.

in iOS:

In your `AppDelegate.m` file these 2:

1.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Your application can present a full screen modal view controller to
    // cover its contents when it moves into the background. If your
    // application requires a password unlock when it retuns to the
    // foreground, present your lock screen or authentication view controller here.

    UIViewController *blankViewController = [UIViewController new];
    blankViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // Pass NO for the animated parameter. Any animation will not complete
    // before the snapshot is taken.
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:blankViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

And this
2.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // This should be omitted if your application presented a lock screen
    // in -applicationDidEnterBackground:
    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NO];
}
```

Source: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1838/_index.html

Found this also:
https://github.com/kayla-tech/react-native-privacy-snapshot